# How to focus a newly-replaced lens on an FPV camera?

Tags: first-person-view, fpv-cameras

I cracked the lens on my FPV camera after a metal pipe jumped in front of my quad...Fortunately, I had another lens from another FPV camera sitting around.  But I'm not sure how far away I should be trying to focus this lens.  Are there any best practices or rules of thumb to follow?

Answer (score 5):

I like to set the drone in a window or take it outside.  Then adjust the focus while looking through the goggles until I get it where it looks good to me.

You may also wish to print out a [focus test pattern](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1L338jakysR4nMFWBZH_MPdaFIWaUWtH3/view) or follow [this detailed tutorial](https://oscarliang.com/focus-fpv-camera-lens/) on focusing an FPV camera.

Comment: I always use the focus test pattern - works great!

Answer (score 1):

FPV cameras usually have a large aperture so you should be able to focus it on something over 10 feet away. If you focus it on something too close, It may be blurry when looking at something further away. If that lens doesn't focus, you may need to buy a lens designed for that specific FPV camera.

You can focus the lens by twisting it.